# React router get current location on main router component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'd like to know how to get the current location from the component I've used to define my routes. For example, I have a component called Routes, which contains all the routes, like this:

```
class Routes extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Nav />
                <header>{customHeader}</header>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                    // Other routes
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }
};
```

However, when I try to access `this.props.location.pathname` as I do in other components, it returns `undefined`.

On the other components I need to use `withRouter` in order to be able to access the `location` information. But I can't use it with the `Routes` component, because it will throw an error.

I don't actually need the `pathname`, I just want to check what route the user is, because I'll render a different header content when accessing a specific page.

Comment: One solution is to do `location.pathname` which is not related to react-router but comes from the browser instead.

Comment: @SaugatAcharya Yeah.. This or moving the verification to another component would be my other options. I just wanted to check if this was possible within the main component.

Comment: Are you getting anything in `this.props.location`?

Comment: @SaugatAcharya No. Since that component is connected with redux, only the data maped to props. However, even when disabling the redux on the component, I can't access the location.

Comment: Just did a quick check, `this.props.location` is in fact accessible from components. Try using react-dev-tools to see what's wrong. Not sure what you are doing with redux.

Comment: are you using withRouter like `withRouter(connect(...)(MyComponent)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your header in a `<Route>` that always renders. Then you'll have access to everything via props.

```
class Routes extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Nav />
                <Route render={(props) => {
                  console.log(props.location)
                  return (
                    <header>{customHeader}</header>
                  )
                }} />

                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                    // Other routes
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }
};
```