# Reactjs obtaining route params inside the component

Tags: reactjs, routes

I am new to react, trying to build a services page - with subpages.

```
<Route path='/:langURL/services/:subPage?' component={Services} />
```

So this invokes the services component - but when I do a console log in the props I am not able to view any route information. How would I start to identify the subjPage types used?

Comment: Are you using react-router?

Comment: react-router-dom - yes  -- import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

Comment: This has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404532/react-router-get-current-location-on-main-router-component check it out.

Comment: what if you want to create lots of subpages for the same component?

Comment: React router's documentations are self-explanatory https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/04-nested-routes

Comment: well - its complicated because its beyond just have 5 pages - and routes for each -- you have 2 language/routes -- then subpages from a parent page